# Two Webcams Taking Stills

Tags: usb, camera, webcam

I’m a bit of a novice, needing to do this for a university project. I need to connect two USB webcams to the RPi and get each to take a still image and save it in “%iimg%i” naming notation to identify the image and the camera it come from. The images are saved onto a USB drive. This all has to run from a script that runs automatically on startup.

Any suggestions as to how to address the cameras as separate entities? And they don’t need to be full colour nor do I need to stream video so any way I can cut down on the data size too, aside from resolution?

EDIT: I'm working on a simple fswebcam function following the advice from Bierschi:

```
# Install fswebcam on RPi:  sudo apt-get install fswebcam
# fswebcam allows for basic photography from a specified device
# ASSUMING CAMERAS 0 AND 1

str DIRECTORY = ""                      #path to write to (undefined)

int takePhoto (int cam, int num):
    if cam == 0:
        str command = "fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 640x480 --no-banner --png " + DIRECTORY + "/1img" + num + ".png"
        os.system (command)
    else:
        str commamd = "fswebcam -d /dev/video1 -r 640x480 --no-banner --png --flip h " + DIRECTORY + "/2img" + num + ".png"
        os.system (command)
return 0
```

Would this activate the cameras correctly? I believe my implementation of the strings is correct.

Comment: It's great to hear you solved your problem, but we don't encourage adding (SOLVED) to the title here at Stack Exchange. Instead, you can click the checkmark below to mark the answer as accepted, which will indicate in the UI that you solved your problem. This will also give @bierschi some rep as a 'thank you'.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Thanks for the information, I'll keep that in mind and accept the answer now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You connect both cameras on the usb ports and if the drivers are configured properly you will see it with following command:

```
ls /dev/video*
```

output:

```
/dev/video0 /dev/video1
```

Now you have access to both devices with `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1`.

Try to take a photo with a software like fswebcam:

```
sudo apt-get install fswebcam
```

and type in:

```
fswebcam -d /dev/video0
```

if this works with both cameras, at this point you can start to write your python script with any camera software like picamera https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/

or with opencv https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

---

example function in python:

```
import os

def takePhoto(cam, num):
  directory = "/home/pi/Desktop/"
  if cam == 0:
     command = "fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 640x480 --no-banner " + directory + "1img" + str(num) + ".png"
     os.system(command)
  else:
   command = "fswebcam -d /dev/video1 -r 640x480 --no-banner --flip h " + directory + "2img" + str(num) + ".png"
   os.system(command)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  takePhoto(0, 1)
```

Be careful, c and python are not the same, so look at the python function definitions. I made a simple example, but please try to use the `subprocess` module in python, because `os.system()` is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Bierschi, so basically after manually listing the attached devices I should just be able to specify which of them to read via fswebcam? As I’m just capturing still images do I even need openCV? In my previous digging I remember seeing that you can take a photo straight from fswebcam. Is that right?

Comment: To give some more context at this early prototyping stage I just need to get the cameras to take the photos and save to the USB drive when called. There are a few other bits but it basically comes down to: move-photo1-photo2-move and repeat.

Comment: yeah you´re right. If you just want to take photo from both cameras, it is sufficient to work with `fswebcam`. This 2 suggestions (picamera, opencv) are useful libs to write your own camera python scripts with a lot of opportunities for your own settings. In your case you can work with 'fswebcam', try the command `fswebcam -h` you get an extensively output with differents options you can select (output to store, resolution, different devices...)

Comment: Thanks again! I’ve used openCV before in a C++ Project (so much easier to use than PCL). The one other feature I’ll need is to flip the image from one camera, I’ll have a look through fswebcam for that, if not then I’ll find another solution. I’ll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: hi again. Got my Pi, got one of the two cameras, second is delayed because seller assumed I only wanted one and got my Pi set up thru VNC and can take snapshots via fswebcam (I’ve learnt so much more about the Pi and Python this past week than ever before!). I’m gettin goth impression that fswebcam is working as a “bang” command when implemented in the command line? So I wouldn’t be able to use it natively in Python scripts, right?

Comment: I prefer to use libs like picamera or opencv to act with cameras in python scripts. But of course you can use command line tools like fswebcam in python scripts. Have a look at the `subprocess` module in python https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html. With this module you can interact with `fswebcam`. Example `subprocess.call(["fswebcam", "-h"])` to see all opportunities for fswebcam

Comment: I'll take a look at that, the name sounds like it'll be quite powerful! I found an example or two online that I've worked off of. I've included the code as an edit to the original, would you care to cast your expert eye over it please? :)

Comment: I give you a suggestion in my answer, please consider this example and try to work with

Comment: thanks again. I’m still getting my head around the syntax differences, thanks for showing me my errors. It looks like if I were to use subprocess it would be the same structure as subprocess is basically simplifying and replacing the older functions, correct? Wrapping my head around the __main__ setup now, I’ll write a test script tomorrow and try it out. Also, is there any way I can repay you for your help? D’you have a “donation” or “tip” service? :)

Comment: No the syntax is a little bit different to `os.system()` but it is explained in detail on the site i mentioned before. Thanks, but you have not to do it. I would suggest you mark this question as answered and if you have a new problem, simply open a new question on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com because this would help other people too